# Ionic: page rendered on web browser is not the same as page on emulated device

Tags: android, css, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using the html5 ionic framework. On chrome (Desktop browser testing), when I like the heart, the color changes from grey to red and when I click on it again, it changes from red to grey (toggle works). On both the emulated iOS device and my android, I can change the button color to red but it doesn't change back to grey once I click on it again.

home.html

```
<ion-view view-title="My Page"
<ion-content class="has-twoheaders">
  <div class="list card">
<div class="item item-body">
<p>
  This is a Card. The header is created from a Thumbnail List item,
  the content is from a card-body consisting of an image and paragraph text. The footer
  consists of tabs, icons aligned left, within the card-footer.
</p>
<p><a ng-click="like()" class="button button-icon heart" ng-class='{liked:liked}'>
<i class="icon ion-heart"></i></a></p>
 </div></div></ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter" >
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>

</html>
```

main.js (the home.html uses the ArticleCtrl Controller)

```
function ArticleCtrl($s,$st,$http) {
  $s.num1 = 0;
  $s.liked = false;
  $s.like = function() {
    if ($s.liked == false) {
       $s.liked = true;
       console.log("Now True");
    } else {
      $s.liked = false;
      console.log("Now False");
    }
   }
angular.module("article",[])
.controller('ArticleCtrl',['$scope','$state','$http', ArticleCtrl])
```

style.css

```
.heart {
   color: grey;
   font-size: 27px;

}

.liked {
  color: red;
}
```

This is the output on the chrome inspector. As you can see, the 'Now True' and 'Now False' toggle works on mobile but the red isn't changing back to grey.
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can u check if there is any error on the device?

Comment: There are no errors on the device.

Comment: so did u try putting `ng-class` like that? `ng-class="{'liked':liked}"`